# Generic OAuth clients integrations

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a product which invokes multiple third party rest api's for certain data fetch.
There are multiple vendor api's which requires oAuth Support. They can grant me account and Client for accessing their api's but my service needs to generate a token using those account and their CI.

How can I build a generic framework to support multiple vendor CI's. 
I consider this bit complex , since some vendors use oAuth1 , some use oAuth 2.. 
Is there any existing solution for this?
How do I handle token refresh?

eg:

One vendor can be google using google CI
other Vendor can be Facebook using their CI.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow is pretty much the same between Facebook and Google, so the backend (and the frontend, *to some extent*) can definitely be designed in a generic manner:

- setup client IDs **only** for the actual client applications (hence the `Authorized JavaScript origins`), and not for the backend, too.
- integrate each client with each OAuth provider
- send data (provider token) the backend/API through a common abstracted model
- validate the token on the server side (this is done differently for each provider, but you could have a IProviderAuthValidator and several inmplementations)
- create account/login etc

Thus, the only particularized bits should be these 2:
 - fetch provider token client side
 - validate said token server side