# using google API for user identification and authentication

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I tried to build a mobile app (client(mobile) <-> server) and i'm going to use google API to authenticate and identify my user and to sync to my server.

**which is the best method to achieve this?**

I was thinking to use below method:

1. Mobile app get authorization code
2. send the code to server
3. server contact google server to get access token
4. both server and mobile client use the access token to access data from google. <-- i**s this access token generated portable? means: i can use it in server as well as in mobile app?**

i'm not sure if above method is the right method that i should use, if it the right method, is there any reference that i can follow (esp. in python) - i tried to read developer.google.com but it's quite humongous type of API there and i got lost...

Thanks for the kind advise

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912777/1791065)